# Explanation in Html collective form

Tags: php, html, laravel

Seeking your help for understanding html collective.
Here are two html code...

```
@foreach($images as $image)
<img class="card-img-top"
   src="{{url($image->image? 'uploads/'.$image->image:'images/noimage.jpg')}}"
   alt="{{$image->description}}" width="100%" height="180px"/>
```

and

```
{{ucwords($image->description)}}
```

I saw this has been used in a tutorial. Can any one help me understanding what url means and why ucwords are used

Thanks!!! in advance

Answer (score 1):

The first one is a laravel helper, you can find all about it in the documentation.

> The url function generates a fully qualified URL to the given path
>   https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/helpers#method-url

the second one is a php native function.

> Uppercase the first character of each word in a string
>   http://php.net/manual/en/function.ucwords.php

Comment: I know about URL. But here in Html Collective, they used in different way, so why I asked.